# Is this code importing something from a folder?

Tags: java

This is part of a demo code, I am trying to learn this code

```
import com.jgrindall.android.connect4.lib.board.*;
```

What is this code doing? is a lib a folder? if it is a folder then where is it located?

Comment: You might want to start with a basic tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 2):

It's importing all classes in the `com.jgrindall.android.connect4.lib.board` package. The source for this can vary - I assume it's in the `com/jgrindall/android/connect4/lib/board` source folders but sometimes it refers to code in an existing `jar` library used in the project.

Comment: How can I find the lib folder?

Comment: You'll need to find out where the source would be. If it's an external library you really can't view the source without decompiling. If it's part of your source code, just use your IDE to browse the source packages.

Answer (score 1):

Import means you want to be able to use the named classes without having to specify their full qualified name. In particular, since this import ends in *, you're saying you want to be able to use any class in the `com.jgrindall.android.connect4.lib.board` package by just giving the short classname -- `Board` rather than `com.jgrindall.android.connect4.lib.board.Board`

Where those classes are loaded from is a separate question, determined by your classpath and classloaders.

Answer (score 1):

it is importing a PAKAGE. You can see the package as folder, and the ending wildchar means import all class in the packge.

If you are using plain source code, then package are folder, but they can also be packaged (no pun intended) in a jar. you can open a jar as a zip, and you will se a manifest file, and thepackage structure.

Also there ase some standard class in their own package in the visrtual machine, and they are all the standard library